# Can't figure out why I'm getting a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, string, charat

I have the following code

```
while (input.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println(line);  // added to test if anything in String, and there is
    int whiteSpace = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while (Character.isWhitespace(line.charAt(j))) {
        whiteSpace++;
        j++;
    }
}
```

When I run it, I get a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0`, which makes no sense to me.  I added a `System.out.print(line)` to test if there is anything in the String and there is. I tried initializing `j` with higher values, still get same thing, just a different `String index out of range: ?`.  Does anyone know why I'm getting this exception? Makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what's in your line, but you should try :

```
while (j < line.length() && Character.isWhitespace(line.charAt(j))) {
    whiteSpace++;
    j++;
}
```

Comment: Your answer was actually the one that fixed my problem completely. I was just trying to find the whitespace in the beginning of a line. The prevoius accepted answer made my formatting all tweeked out.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try something more like this:

```
while(j<line.length) {
    if(Character.isWhitespace(line.charAt(j))) {
        whiteSpace++;
    }
    j++;
}
```

It's probably closer to what you're trying to do.  What you have now, if it worked, would only increment `j` whenever there was a `whiteSpace`, and as such, even if you weren't getting the error, you'd be stuck in an infinite loop unless you had a `String` that consisted of only white spaces.  The above code will increment `j` on every character (so you check each character once and only once through the entire string), but increments `whiteSpace` only when `Character.isWhitespace(line.charAt(j))` returns `true`.

EDIT: Given the re-clarification of what you're actually trying to do, just drop the variable `j` as it muddies the readability (hence my confusion).

```
while(whiteSpace<line.length && Character.isWhitespace(line.charAt(whiteSpace)))
    { whiteSpace++; }
```

Comment: @peeskillet If the answer provided solved your problem, please check the `accept answer` button, so it will close your question.  ;)

Comment: Yeah I have to wait another minute

Comment: Sorry, I had to un-accept to give the accept to the answer that fully solved my problem, which was just figuring out whitespace in at the beginning of a line.  Your answer kinda tweeked my desired formatting

Comment: @peeskillet Then you probably don't need the variable `j` at all.  Your code would be far better off without it as it muddles the readability.

Comment: how would I get the whitespace without the `j` ?

Comment: @peeskillet See my edit.  In your code, as well as the now accepted answer, variables `j` and `whiteSpace` are redundant and doing the same thing.

Comment: I see what you're saying. Just replace `j` in the condition with `whitesapce`. You're right.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you are incrementing j++ and then using it in :

```
Character.isWhitespace(line.charAt(j))
```

If you only have one char on the line, which is a whitespace, then on the next iteration, it would try to reach next char, which doesn't exist.

Hence you might have to check if char is not null, and then if it is a whitespace. 
Or brake if the next char is null.